# CSS4 Grid-Structural pseudo-class polyfill (:nth-column)

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-grid, pseudo-class, polyfills

I have a CSS grid layout, where I would like to add a margin to each even column. The `:nth-column` pseudo-class would be nice but won’t be supported anytime soon.

Are there any polyfills I could use or do I have to write my own?

Comment: You don't want to polyfill the grid-structural pseudo-classes if you want to select elements by their position in a *CSS grid layout*. Those pseudo-classes were not designed and are not intended for that purpose, and attempting to polyfill them to do something else will cause conflicts with browsers in the future. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162286/are-there-selectors-that-target-elements-in-certain-grid-positions/44162595#44162595). If you must implement a selector, implement a custom selector and know that it is non-standard.

Comment: Oh okay, I missed their purpose then … what should they be used for? Implementing a custom selector is not necessary. The offset is not critical for the layout, so I would avoid huge workarounds to implement it.

Comment: Ah okay, you are referring to the CSS grid layout. So those selectors are table-layout specific?

Comment: Yes; at least in HTML, tables are the only thing that have grid-structural semantics. Selectors were never designed to match elements by their styles since using them in CSS would be problematic.

Comment: ah okay, thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out about [sel](https://github.com/amccollum/sel), but if there is anything more lightweight (feature specific polyfills), that would be nice.