# Referring to last or first item in new column of flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

is there a way to automatically address the last or first item of a column in a flexbox container?
I would like the items to have a division line like this:
[flexbox items with division lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d322u.png)

The last one in each column should not have a border-bottom.

It's not a problemn to do it "manually" with nth-of-child, but items will constantly be added or removed, so I'm looking for a more elegant way to solve this. Something like".flex-item:last-in-column".

Answer (score 1):

## No

> A similar problem exists with flexbox: **there are no selectors for matching specific flex items based on how they are laid out**. In general, there are no selectors matching elements based on their layout as governed by CSS. Selectors only match elements based on document semantics (source order, etc).
>
> <sup>[BoltClock in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162286/are-there-selectors-that-target-elements-in-certain-grid-positions)</sup>